# Websockets with AngularJS and Spring Boot

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, websocket

I am trying to put together a simple example WebSocket app that uses AngularJS and Spring Boot. I am using [this angularjs websocket library](https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-websocket)

The issue is that i am unable to send anything from client to server. There are no errors on the front end and nothing logged no errors on the back end.

Websocket config:

```
package org.example.project;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements 
WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/report");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
       registry.addEndpoint("/socket").
           setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

Websocket endpoint implementation:

```
package org.example.project;

import java.util.Date;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class WebSocketController {

    private final SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    WebSocketController(SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/uc/status/request")
    public void onReceivedMessage(String message) {

        System.out.println(" THIS CAME FROM WS CLIENT ");
        this.template.convertAndSend("/uc/status/report", 
            "received " + message);
    }

}
```

Angular client implementation:

```
'use strict'

var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ngWebSocket'
])
app.controller("MyController", function($scope, $http, $websocket) {

    // path to the end point is actually /app/uc/status/request
    // unable to add end point path when connecting
    // and don't know how to subscribe
    var ws = $websocket('ws://localhost:8080/socket/websocket/');

    ws.onMessage(function(event) { 
        console.log('message: ', event);
    });

    ws.onError(function(event) {
        console.log("error");
    });

    ws.onClose(function(event) { 

    });

    ws.onOpen(function(event) { 
        console.log('connection open');
    });

    // nothing happens when this call is made
    ws.send("message content", "/app/uc/status/request");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.template.convertAndSend("/uc/status/report", 
    "received " + message);
```

Your destination (first param) is wrong. You registered your broker channel with destination prefix `/report`, so you must publish/subscribe to such destination prefix. So change it to

```
this.template.convertAndSend("/report", 
    "received " + message);
```

And for front end client to subscribe and send to a particular destination

```
// sorry I dont work with angular below is mostly copied.
connect() {
  const socket = new SockJS('/socket');
  this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

  const _this = this;
  this.stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
    _this.stompClient.subscribe('/report', function (data) {
      // do something with received data
    });
  });
}
// send message to destination
send() {
  this.stompClient.send(
    '/app/uc/status/request', // roughly put, ur applicationDestinationPrefix + @MessageMapping
    {},
    "my message"
  );
}
```

Depending on your application needs, You can add whatever path you want after `/report`, such as `/report/myreport1, /report/myreport2`, for multiple topics or queues. Note that the prefix you defined in `enableSimpleBroker("/report")` doesn't really matter in the naming sense as it works fine for Spring's in-memory message broker. For other dedicated brokers, such as ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ, you should be using `/topic` for one to many (many subscribers) and `/queue` for one to one (one receiver). read more on https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html